# How to use variable from previous scope in Python

Tags: python, scope

I have the following code:

```
def test():
    def printA():
        def somethingElse():
            pass
        print(a)
        aHA = a[2]


    a = [1, 2, 3]
    while True:
        printA()

test()
```

I've noticed that this code will work fine, but if I change the `aHA` to just `a`, it says `a` is not defined.

Is there any way to set `a` to another value within printA?

Comment: In Python 2.7, no, this is not possible. In Python 3, yes.

Comment: Ah, I guess this would be a reason to move up to Python 3 then.

Comment: Ah, I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error?rq=1) which helps to explain why this happens too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3, you can set the variable as nonlocal

```
def test():
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    def printA():
        nonlocal a
        def somethingElse():
            pass
        print(a)
        a = a[2]

    while True:
        printA()

test()
```